# CentOS 7.0 1406 installation fails on NetworkManager time out

Tags: service, centos7, supermicro, networkmanager, anaconda

Installing CentOS 7 on Supermicro [SYS-6027TR-HTRF](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/2U/6027/SYS-6027TR-HTRF.cfm). The installer stops at:

```
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut:
Activation of org.freedesktop.NetworkManager timed out
```

Very similar issue to described below (screenshot matches mine output):
http://blog.endpoint.com/2015/01/centos-7-on-hetzner-server-with-more.html

Could the problem lie with network interfaces named: `em1`, `em2`,…etc? (I've checked and that's my case too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the issue on a similar supermicro server. After messing around with udev names and trying to get NetworkManager to be happy, I gave up and just ran the installer using vnc with the following parameters to pass on boot:

> vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img inst.vnc inst.vncpassword=secretpass ksdevice=em1 ip=1.2.3.4 gateway=1.2.3.4 netmask=255.255.255.0 nameserver=1.2.3.4 inst.repo=http://mirror.cs.pitt.edu/centos/7/os/x86_64

Obviously replace IP, gateway, netmask, nameserver and the inst.repo with your values. Once the server comes up (systemd-udev on the initrd renames eth0 to em1!), just connect with a VNC client (TightVNC?) and configure away!

Not sure about everyone else, but i'm disabling NetworkManager the moment I get in.